# Why is ServiceStack JwtAuthProvider being invoked when service is specified to authenticate with GithubAuthProvider?

Tags: authentication, servicestack

Exploring the `ServiceStack` authentication providers for the first time. Have gradually built up a test project by adding `BasicAuthProvider` and when that worked, added `GithubAuthProvider`. The last one added was `JwtAuthProvider` and that works as well. When I retested authentication with any of the previous authentication providers such as Github, for example, I find that the `JwtAuthProvider` lambda function for `CreatePayloadFilter` is still being invoked. This was not expected.

The `AuthFeature` plugin is as follows:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new PartnerWebSession(), 
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new JwtAuthProvider(appSettings) { ... },
        new BasicAuthProvider(),       //Sign-in with HTTP Basic Auth
        new GithubAuthProvider(appSettings)
    }));
```

I have created `BasicHello`, `GithubHello` and `JwtHello` service models with different end points for use with each of the authentication providers with routes:

```
/basic/{Name}
/github/{Name}
/jwt/{Name}
```

The `AuthenticateAttribute` has been attached to the `Service` classes designed to work with these models and they each specify the Provider to use, e.g.:

```
    [Authenticate(Provider = "basic")]

    public class BasicAuthentication : Service
    {
        public object Any(BasicHello request)
        {
            return new BasicHelloResponse { Result = $"{nameof(BasicAuthentication)} says Hello, {request.Name}!" };
        }
    }
```

Testing using Visual Studio debug and Chrome browser. Have ensured that no previous cookies JWT are hanging around from previous tests by clearing cookies for all time. I enter the URL:

http://localhost:52070/api/github?name=stephen

This takes me to the ServiceStack rendered authentication screen with login dialogue and "Sign In with Github" button. Click the "Sign In with Github" button which takes me to the "Sign in to GitHub" page provided by GitHub. Successfully authenticate, and then code execution hits a breakpoint I've set in `CreatePayloadFilter` lambda of the `JwtAuthProvider`.

I did not expect this. Is this an error or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the JWT AuthProvider registered it populates the successful Auth Response with a populated JWT Token that encapsulates the partial authenticated session.

The stateless client JWT Token (i.e. instead of server session cookies) can then be used to make authenticated requests after a successful OAuth Sign In.

Comment: This answers the question, i.e. the behaviour is by design and as a result I reread the JWT AuthProvider documentation, but it wasn't much clearer. I simplified my JWTAuthProvider  by removing any custom code  for any of the provider's properties and tested again and again monitoring requests and responses with Fiddler, but could not find a JWT anywhere in any of the response headers. Can't work out whether this is supposed to be implicitly handled or whether additional code is needed.